# Replace all characters to ASCII in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have an input string as follows: `"ABC1134M001020000089"`.

I want to convert the string to integer format. One of the methods I thought of was by replacing A,B,C,M to its respective ASCII Values.

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: One way: `tblMap [ auto_increment ID, string_value ]` and just use the ID.  (Your approach would exceed an ints 32 bits btw)

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. I want to avoid this as i have huge dataset (in Billions). Implementing it this way would mean heavy joins. Wanted to know your views on it.

Comment: Can you say why it needs to be a number?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am trying to keep numbers so that joins will be faster. No other specific reason.

Comment: How do you know that the comparison of strings in the join operation is a problem? Did you run benchmarks on it?

Comment: Have you heard of *"if it ain't broke don't fix it?"* You seem to want to update billions of rows to replace values used for joins (which I assume currently work) but you are probably seeking performance gains. Think through the implications of what you are seeking. It's dangerous and has no guarantee of being the performance silver bullet